# Function imnoise() in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why is the mean for imnoise() limited to [0,1]? Is there a way to extend it?

Answer (score 3):

if you are just trying to add gaussian noise to yor image, you could do it 'manually'

```
>> image = image + mean*randn( size(mage) );
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imnoise.html), all the numerical parameters for IMNOISE are normalized by the image intensity.  1 indicates the maximum intensity for the image.  It isn't possible to set a pixel to a value outside that range.